# Can you design highly detailed miniature model trains, cars, buildings, etc, for 3d printing with Blender? If you can how?

Tags: modeling

[image: enter image descriptio here]
Im starting a business to design and make highly detailed 3d printed miniature models of trains, vehicles, boats, buildings, etc. Don't have much experience with 3d designing, not sure of what I need for cad. Want to make my designs on Shapeways. Appreciate it if anyone can help, Dan.

Comment: Unless you are ready to deal with the intricacies of [proper topology](http://topologyguides.com) you'd probably be advised to use a either a NURBS or Solid modelling based software instead. Bad news is there are no free examples.

Comment: Looked into some solid modeling software, seems like more than necessary for a small business, but I have contacted SolidWorks. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Closest to free is [MoI](http://moi3d.com) which is relatively cheap for this type of software, considering the competition. And excellent quality too, I've used it myself. There is also [FreeCAD](https://www.freecadweb.org/) which is more of a parametric tool. But this just to say that Blender is fully capable of doing what you want, just takes some getting used to.

Comment: Can mol create very small details? Have you ever used it for 3d printing?

Comment: Never used it specifically for 3D printing, but Moi is a joy to use. It is particularly aimed at small projects and single pieces, not full fledged modelling of large structures. Not in terms of physical size, more in terms of complexity or scope.